# select rows where dates are equal and id's are equal and count these rows as one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, group-by

I have a database where I have id, new_name,product_id, date

```
1162        DC: 10us      1049902   2013-07-19 
1163        DC: 12us      1049902   2013-07-19 
1164        DC: 30us      1049902   2013-07-19 
1165        Top           1049902   2017-07-30 
1166        A:123         202302    2013-07-21 
1167        A:255         2023025   2013-07-21
```

I need to choose the rows where date are equal (every row's date for example = 2013-07-19 and every row's product_id =  (for example) 1049902) and count these rows as 1 row

so:

```
   DC 1049902  = 2 (because there are two different dates that's why 2 besause it is summary (the names are differenet it doesn't matter)
   A 202302 = 1
   A 2023025 = 1
```

(after the query I just substr() the string)

and so on...

I tried to do it like this:

```
   select new_name, COUNT(new_name) AS n from table WHERE date<='".$today."' AND date>= '".$two_weeks_ago."' GROUP BY day(date) ORDER BY n DESC
```

but it counts me every row

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Parado, check this code:

```
select brand_name, count(*) AS num 
from (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(new_name, ':', 1) as brand_name 
from table 
WHERE date<='".$american_today."' AND date>= '".$two_weeks_ago."' 
GROUP BY day(date), products_id) 
as brands  group by brand_name ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 5
```

that's work better, I did it, because your code worked wrong
Sorry, if I hadn't told you more information.

Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
select new_name, product_id,COUNT(day(date)) AS n 
from table 
WHERE date<='".$today."' AND date>= '".$two_weeks_ago."' 
GROUP BY new_name, product_id 
ORDER BY n DESC
```

EDIT:
With `substring(new_name,0,5)` from OP

```
select substring(new_name,0,5) as new_name, product_id,COUNT(day(date)) AS n 
from table 
WHERE date<='".$today."' AND date>= '".$two_weeks_ago."' 
GROUP BY substring(new_name,0,5), product_id 
ORDER BY n DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but if the new_names are different, how will it be? thank you ))

Comment: something like this: select new_name, COUNT(day(date)) AS n from table WHERE date<='2013-07-26' AND date>= '2013-07-12' GROUP BY products_id,day(date) ORDER BY n DESC

Comment: I have just edited the question where the new_names are different. Thank you )

Comment: No, they are all diferrent. Sometimes they are equal but there is no conection between them

Comment: they are the same where products_id is the same and the date is the same

Comment: select new_name, COUNT( distinct products_id) AS n from products_options_values_history WHERE date<='".$american_today."' AND date>= '".$two_weeks_ago."' GROUP BY products_id, day(date) ORDER BY n DESC .... maybe like this?

Comment: after the query I just substr() the string, it doesn't matter

Comment: you mean to substr the new_name to length till " : " ?

Comment: couldn't you write me your query mysql tells me that threse is an error to GROUP BY substring(new_name)

Comment: oh, now it is fine, I just forgot to rename smth)

Comment: oh my God, it hasn't solved the problem. select substring(new_name,0,5) AS s, products_id,COUNT(day(date)) AS n 
from table
WHERE date<='2013-07-26' AND date>= '2013-07-12' 
GROUP BY s, products_id 
ORDER BY n DESC

Comment: I just opened the table, input the products_id and the date (from the 2013-07-12) and it showed me 2 differents in the date column

Comment: substring(new_name,0,5)... 5 is not for sure, i wrote it so because I wll find out from what position I need to substr() only in while mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

Group by product_id and new_name both

```
SELECT new_name, COUNT(new_name) AS n 
FROM table 
WHERE date<='".$today."' AND date>= '".$two_weeks_ago."' 
GROUP BY new_name,product_id
ORDER BY n DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT `new_name`, COUNT(`new_name`) AS n 
     FROM table 
        WHERE `date`<='".$today."' AND `date` >= '".$two_weeks_ago."' 
        GROUP BY `product_id`, `date` 
        ORDER BY n DESC
```